# Interact with my running application

Tags: vb.net, interaction

**Given**:

A list-based application with an advanced user-system based on two applications:

1. Main-Tool

   - Displays all Entrys with possible filters
   - Create entrys
   - Delete entrys
   - Edit entrys
   - Filter entrys to only see specific ones
   - ...you get the point
2. Creation-Tool

   - Reads specific informations out of a file and opens the same mask as the Main-Tools creation function as a separated application.

**The Problem**:

So I have my Creation-Tool and the Main-Tools function to create entrys as well. So each time i am changing a thing on the creation mask, i have to do it in two applications.

**The Solution**:

There has to be a way to call functions of my application from the outside.

**The Question**:

How can i get rid of the second application? The Main-Application has more informations (Logged in user for example) than the Creation-Tool, so i want to get rid of the Creation-Tool. Having a second application that calls my main application is okay.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You want to get rid of the second application, then you say that _"having a second application that calls my main application is okay"_. -- As for communicating with your main application: Google _"Interprocess communication"_.

Comment: Interprocess communication seems to be the keyword i've been looking for. You helped me a lot already! Thanks!
For the question; Having a second application is okay. I just dont want to do every change twice so the creation itself should only happen in the main tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to move all of your functionality into a separate library. Using inter-process communication would require both programs to be running. Whereas if you had two programs that shared the same dll, that would solve your duplicate code issue and each program can be run independently. Once you have all your functionality separated from the user interface and moved into it's own dll, then consolidating the UI of both applications into one will be much easier.